# R: issue when using small polygons to extract minimum value of raster

Tags: r, extract, polygon

I have a small polygon (area is 83 ha as shown below). I use it to extract some statistics from a raster layer which has a resolution of 81 ha per grid-cell. From below, you can see that this polygon partially covers four grid-cells in the raster. The mean value of raster that is covered by polygon turns out to be fine, but both the maximum and minimum value is wrong, they are both 5196. but actually, one is 5185, the other is 5215. I thought maybe the grid cells with min/max values are relatively less covered (see the weights). But I have already used small=TRUE here. Please let me know how to address the issue. Thank you very much!

> lr.deficomp[10010,]@data$hectares
>
> [1] **83.16897**
>
> extract(revenue_comb, lr.deficomp[10010,], weights=TRUE)
>
> [[1]]
>           value     weight

**[1,] 5185.582 0.04504505**

**[2,] 5196.723 0.54054054**

**[3,] 5201.487 0.28828829**

**[4,] 5215.879 0.12612613**

> extract(revenue_comb, lr.deficomp[10010,], fun=min, na.rm=TRUE)
>
> ```
>      [,1]
> ```
>
> [1,] **5196.723**
>
> extract(revenue_comb, lr.deficomp[10010,], fun=max, na.rm=TRUE)
>
> ```
>      [,1]
> ```
>
> [1,] **5196.723**
>
> extract(revenue_comb, lr.deficomp[10010,], weights=TRUE, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
>
> ```
>     [,1]
> ```
>
> [1,] **5200.01**